# How can I set TimeZone for my ASP.NET (MVC) Application

Tags: asp.net, datetime, timezone

My Application hosted at server in time zone which differs from mine. All date in database is not correct for my time zone.
How can I set my time zone for Application or how I can convert date to my time zone on output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the time zone for the process - use [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) from .NET 3.5 and higher to perform the relevant conversions.

Of course, that assumes you know the time zone that the data will come back in from the database... usually database records are kept in UTC, but not always...

Comment: just to add, keep all your dates in the db in UTC, and just convert them when you need to display them.

Comment: How to deal with reporting, especially with grouping by dates? For UTC some facts are in one day but with local time the same facts may be splited on two days. :(

Answer (score 1):

There's very easy way to do it. Simply get the current UTC time and your timezone. Convert UTC to your timezone. Here's how you do it.

```
 DateTime date1 = DateTime.UtcNow;                   
 TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("YOUR TIME ZONE (e.g. Pakistan Standard Time)");               
 DateTime date2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date1, tz);
```

Set your Time Zone in tz and then use "date2" anywhere.